# Resume file uploads from previous session in fine-uploader

Tags: fine-uploader

What is the general approach for resuming previously interrupted uploads with fine-uploader after the browser has been closed?  I've searched the docs and played with the code, but am not having any success.

I envisioned re-populating the uploader with resumable files along with "Resume" and "Cancel" buttons (like a PAUSED upload).  I thought I could use `getResumableFilesData()` and `addInitialFiles()`, but the status defaults to COMPLETED.  If I'm supposed to use `addFiles()`, then what is the best way to construct the input values?  Or, am I on the wrong path entirely?

Please forgive me if I'm missing something obvious.  I am looking for helpful nudge in the right direction.

Thanks in advance!

Here is my fine-uploader template:

```
  <script type="text/template" id="qq-template">
    <div class="qq-uploader-selector qq-uploader" qq-drop-area-text="Drop files here">
        <div class="qq-total-progress-bar-container-selector qq-total-progress-bar-container progress total_progress">
            <div role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" 
                class="qq-total-progress-bar-selector progress-bar"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="qq-upload-drop-area-selector qq-upload-drop-area" qq-hide-dropzone>
            <span class="qq-upload-drop-area-text-selector"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="qq-upload-button-selector btn btn-default">
            <div><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> Browse
                Files</div>
        </div>
        <br><br>
            <span class="qq-drop-processing-selector qq-drop-processing">
                <span>Processing dropped files...</span>
                <span class="qq-drop-processing-spinner-selector qq-drop-processing-spinner"></span>
            </span>
        <ul class="qq-upload-list-selector qq-upload-list" aria-live="polite" aria-relevant="additions removals">
            <li>
                <div class="qq-progress-bar-container-selector progress">
                    <div role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" class="qq-progress-bar-selector progress-bar"></div>
                </div>
                <span class="qq-upload-spinner-selector qq-upload-spinner"></span>
                <span class="qq-upload-file-selector qq-upload-file"></span>
                <span class="qq-edit-filename-icon-selector qq-edit-filename-icon" aria-label="Edit filename"></span>
                <input class="qq-edit-filename-selector qq-edit-filename" tabindex="0" type="text">
                <span class="qq-upload-size-selector qq-upload-size"></span>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm qq-upload-cancel-selector">Cancel</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm qq-upload-retry-selector">Retry</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm qq-upload-delete-selector qq-upload-delete">Delete</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm qq-upload-pause-selector">Pause</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm qq-upload-continue-selector">Continue</button>

                <span role="status" class="qq-upload-status-text-selector qq-upload-status-text"></span>
            </li>
        </ul>

        <dialog class="qq-alert-dialog-selector">
            <div class="qq-dialog-message-selector"></div>
            <div class="qq-dialog-buttons">
                <button type="button" class="qq-cancel-button-selector">Close</button>
            </div>
        </dialog>

        <dialog class="qq-confirm-dialog-selector">
            <div class="qq-dialog-message-selector"></div>
            <div class="qq-dialog-buttons">
                <button type="button" class="qq-cancel-button-selector">No</button>
                <button type="button" class="qq-ok-button-selector">Yes</button>
            </div>
        </dialog>

        <dialog class="qq-prompt-dialog-selector">
            <div class="qq-dialog-message-selector"></div>
            <input type="text">
            <div class="qq-dialog-buttons">
                <button type="button" class="qq-cancel-button-selector">Cancel</button>
                <button type="button" class="qq-ok-button-selector">Ok</button>
            </div>
        </dialog>
    </div>
</script>
```

Here is my fine-loader configuration.

```
    var uploader = $('#fine-uploader').fineUploader({
        template: 'qq-template',
        debug: true,
        callbacks: {
            onAllComplete: function(succeeded, failed) {
                $('#doclib_tree').jstree(true).refresh()
                if (failed.length > 0) {
                    alert("Error: Some files were not uploaded");
                } else {
                    if (succeeded.length > 0 ) {
                        alert("Successfully uploaded " + succeeded.length + " file(s)");
                    }
                    this.reset();
                    toggle_upload();
                }
            },
            onError: function(id, name, errorReason, xhrOrXdr) {
                alert("Error uploading " + name + ".  Reason: " + errorReason)
            },
            onSubmit: function(id, name) {
                var promise = new qq.Promise();
                var dest = document.getElementById('dest_label').innerHTML.replace(/ &gt; /g, "/")
                $.ajax({
                    'type': 'POST',
                    'async': false,
                    'url': "/documents/exists" ,
                    'data': {
                        'parents' : get_path(dest),
                        'name': name,
                    },
                    'success': function(data, textStatus, jqHXR) {
                        if ( check_session(data) ) {
                            promise.failure();
                        } else {
                            if (confirm("The file '" + dest + "/" + name + "' already exists.  Replace?"))
                                promise.success();
                            else
                                promise.failure();
                        }
                    },
                    'error': function(jqHXR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        promise.success();
                    }
                });
                return promise;
            },
        },
        chunking: {
            enabled: true,
            partSize: 20000000, // 20MB
            success: {
                endpoint: "/documents/upload?success=1",
            }
        },
        resume: {
            enabled: true
        },
        request: {
            endpoint: "/documents/upload",
        },
        autoUpload: true
    });
```

Here is the bit of code where I would like to retrieve and display resumable files upon initialization.  I do indeed get a populated `resumes` array.

```
    var resumes = uploader.fineUploader('getResumableFilesData')
    if ( resumes > 0 ) {
        // Should I be doing something different here?
        uploader.fineUploader('addFiles', resumes)
    }
```

Comment: Look at most large file uploaders, 99% of the time they are desktop/mobile applications due to the fact on how browsers handle things. A web browser is usually so sand boxed that its hard to tell where a file is left off at as soon as its released in memory. I have seen some really hacky stuff done in Internet Explorer but that is a headache all in its own. Do you have anything you can show us that you were working on?

Comment: The key is that your user _must_ re-submit the interrupted file. There is no way for the browser to reach into your filesystem and retrieve a file without user intervention. See my answer for more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Fine Uploader stores information about the progress of interrupted files in the browser's local storage.](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/features/resume.html) If the same file is added to the uploader again in a subsequent browser/upload session, Fine Uploader will begin uploading that file starting with the last failed/interrupted chunk.

If you want to prompt your user to re-add interrupted files, you can certainly do so. [`getResumableFilesData()`](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/methods.html#getResumableFilesData) will tell you about interrupted files that can be resumed, provided the user re-submits those files to the uploader via DnD or a file input element (or the [`addFiles`](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/methods.html#addFiles) API method).

Comment: Perfect.  That's what I wasn't getting (i.e., that the user has to add the file again).  My code works properly as-is when I re-add the file!  Thank you so much!  By the way, the plug-in is awesome!

Comment: @GregMorris so it is not possible to auto-resume say if the window was closed mid upload? The user has to add the files right? The only thing fineuploader stores is progress data.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use alternatives, I suggest these modern libraries:

https://github.com/23/resumable.js

and

https://github.com/flowjs/flow.js (that is based on same resumable.js)